# Parse string with words surrounded by curly braces to array in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a string like this:

```
"asdf {FIELD1}\n adf {FIELD2} asdf adsf{FIELD3}asdf {FIELD4}"
```

What I need is an array containing the strings "FIELD1", "FIELD2", "FIELD3", "FIELD4". In other words: Find all text enclosed by { and } and put it to an array. Is there an easy/clever way to do this with Python 3.5 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

easy with regular expressions as long as the braces cannot be nested:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}","asdf {FIELD1}\n adf {FIELD2} asdf adsf{FIELD3}asdf {FIELD4}")
['FIELD1', 'FIELD2', 'FIELD3', 'FIELD4']
```

`findall` conveniently creates a `list` of all matching expressions in the input.

the `\{(.*?)\}` expression extracts the data between the curly braces (that you have to escape because they are special in regex language (repeating groups), even if they aren't interpreted as such in this particular context, so they *could* be omitted).

The parentheses are used to only extract the non-curly brace part and the `.*?` makes sure that you're matching the closest closing curly brace (non-greedy mode).

It's also good practice to use raw string prefix for regexes (even if it's not absolutely useful here, it avoids the infamous `\1` and `\b` traps)

Comment: is there a need to escape `{` always translated as literal unles used in a special character format

Comment: @Onyambu technically no... they're only special after a previous expression... but there's no harm :) (if you suddenly through in a pattern to match previously, then things will go odd without the escaping though)

Comment: @Onyambu you're right. They aren't absolutely necessary in that particular case.

Comment: Two nitpicks: 1) The curly braces don't need to be escaped in this case, since they only have special meaning when there are numbers inside of them (like `{2}` or `{1,4}`). 2) Please use raw string literals for regex patterns. Show newbies the right way to do it.

Comment: @Onyambu but why? :p

Comment: If one wanted bizarre approaches to this you could also use: `[el[1] for el in string.Formatter().parse(the_string)]` :p

Comment: @JonClements clever. Are you on answering-strike? this could be a cool answer

Comment: @Jean-François nope... it's just complete abuse of the string formatting system and isn't at all a practical answer... just didn't want to be outdone by the splitting solution :p (plus - thought you might enjoy it)

Comment: I _do_ enjoy it, actually.

Comment: and there was me thinking I needed help :p

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake you can also use `str.split` to obtain your desired output:

```
s = "asdf {FIELD1}\n adf {FIELD2} asdf adsf{FIELD3}asdf {FIELD4}"
[i.split('}')[0] for i in s.split('{')[1:]]
```